# Create a Custom Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a custom WCF binding.  I want to simulate msmq using a set of database tables to achieve the same principle.

There is a lot of negative attention attached to MSMQ at the company where I work due to previous projects that failed attempting to use it.  I myself have never had an issue when working with MSMQ once it was setup.

Is it possible to create custom wcf bindings for asynchronous queue based services?

And if it is where could I find good resources on how to achieve it?

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - there's a few samples floating around, both on MSDN and elsewhere. There are custom binding for e.g. UDP, SMTP and others. And I had the pleasure of having to write a custom binding for a legacy SOAP 1.1 web service with ISO-8859-1 encoding.

So from my own experience, I can confirm, yes, it is possible. Not easy or straightforward, but possible.